# "Trying to get property of non-object" With relations Yii2

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, foreach, yii2

i have this error "Trying to get property of non-object" With relations (two tables) in Yii2

```
$modelSK = SarparastKhanevar::find()->with('tahtTakafols')->where(['code' => $skCode])->all();
```

in this print_r($modelSK) i have result from two tables but i have error in print_r($modelSK->tahtTakafols)

```
Array
(
    [0] => app\models\SarparastKhanevar Object
        (
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [code] => 1493708638
                    [s_id] => 1
                    [u_id] => 6
                )

            [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [code] => 1493708638
                    [s_id] => 1
                    [u_id] => 6
                )

            [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [tahtTakafols] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => app\models\TahtTakafol Object
                                (
                                    [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4
                                            [sk_id] => 2
                                            [code] => 1493728441
                                        )

                                    [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4
                                            [sk_id] => 2
                                            [code] => 1493728441
                                        )

                                    [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
                                    [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
                                    [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
                                    [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => app\models\TahtTakafol Object
                                (
                                    [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 5
                                            [sk_id] => 2
                                            [code] => 1493728450
                                        )

                                    [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 5
                                            [sk_id] => 2
                                            [code] => 1493728450
                                        )

                                    [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
                                    [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
                                    [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
                                    [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
            [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

echo result in Foreach:

```
                $i = 0;
                foreach($modelSK as $model)
                {
                    $list[$i]['id'] = $model->id;
                    $list[$i]['code'] = $model->code;
                    $list[$i]['s_id'] = $model->s_id;
                    $list[$i]['u_id'] = $model->u_id;

                    $j = 0;
                    foreach($modelSK->tahtTakafols as $modelTt)
                    {
                        $list[$i][$j]['id'] = $modelTt->id;
                        $list[$i][$j]['sk_id'] = $modelTt->sk_id;
                        $list[$i][$j]['code'] = $modelTt->code;
                        $j++;
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
$modelSK->tahtTakafols
```

You cannot access it like this, as this is an `Array of Object`. And you are using the `$model` variable in two different loops. The outer loop is OK but inside it

```
foreach($modelSK->tahtTakafols as $model)
```

this line is having issue.

Comment: i change my foreach but i have error. please check first post i change my code

Comment: Changed code still have `foreach($modelSK->tahtTakafols as $modelTt)` in it

Answer (score 0):

`$model->tahtTakafols` not `$modelSK->tahtTakafols`